# Is there a way to fetch all posts in a user's facebook wall through graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, date, search

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/feed
```

gives posts from recent to older,

I'm currently fetching all of them until I pass the required date, and filter only posts of required date. It will be much simplified and efficient if there is a API to fetch posts of a specific date. So wondering if there is any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) instead of Graph API for your case. You can query the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table to retrieve the status created between certain dates. For example to retrieve status updates between 21th June and 28th June you can create FQL like

```
SELECT post_id,message,actor_id, attachment, description 
FROM stream 
WHERE created_time > 1371790800 and created_time < 1372442741
      and source_id = me() and actor_id = me()
```